# Break activity classes into multiple files

Tags: android

> This is the main activity
>   I am trying to move like classes to a new file
>   Once I do, I am not able to successfully call the class
>   The following code generates a null pointer, though the pointer is not null
>   I cannot simply change the savedTrainInfo class to static because
>   then the file routines will not work.  There must be a simple solution
>   I need to keep my classes separate for clarity.

```
import mp.trains.conductor.savedTrainInfo;
public class trains extends Activity 
  {
  private savedTrainInfo msavedTrainInfo;
  protected static Context context;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    trains.context=getApplicationContext();  
    msavedTrainInfo=new savedTrainInfo();
    msavedTrainInfo.getTrainAttributes();
    }
  }
```

> new file
>   many functions here; mainly file I/O
>   These all work fine if there are located in the main activity trains
>   You are correct.  The error seems to be in if (readStartupFile(trainAttributes)==false)

```
public class savedTrainInfo extends trains
  {
  public void getTrainAttributes()
    {
    trainAttributes=new String [10];
if (readStartupFile(trainAttributes)==false)
  {
  fileLine=0;
  }
else
  {
  try 
    {
    fileLine = Integer.parseInt(trainAttributes[0].toString());
    } 
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe) 
    {
    System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
    } 
  }
    }

  public  boolean readStartupFile(String objects[])
    {
    try 
    {
// InputStream fHandle = openFileInput("startupTrains.txt");
InputStream fHandle = trains.context.openFileInput("startupTrains.txt");
if (fHandle != null) 
  {
  // prepare the file for reading
  InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(fHandle);
  BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
  String line;
  line = buffreader.readLine();
  if (line == null)
    {
    fHandle.close();
    return false;
    }
  else
    {
    String[] item = (line).split(",");                  
    objects[0]=item[0].toString();                      
    fHandle.close();
    }
  return true;
  }
else
  {
  return false;
  }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e2) 
  {
  return false;
  } 
catch (IOException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
return false;
}
}

  }
```

Comment: Two things: where's the null pointer exception? and, I think we would need to see the "many functions here" since you might be referencing something that is valid (e.g. using `this` as a `Context`) in the Activity context but not when you refactor that class out.

Comment: The null pointer is generated when msavedTrainInfo.getTrainAttributes(); is called.  The many functions are all called from getTrainAttributes() which is never getting executed.  The null pointer exception occurs first.  Again, these routines all execute properly when added to the main activity trains.

Comment: The actual error is InputStream fHandle = openFileInput("startupTrains.txt"); in readStartupFile(String objects[]).  I stepped the debugger through to this point.

Comment: Solved.  Thanks to pointing out that somewhere else was the exception.  Solution: InputStream fHandle = trains.context.openFileInput("startupTrains.txt");

Comment: @Marty, write your answer down and mark it as solved.  Otherwise it's just hanging there in 'unanswered questions'.

Comment: Also, with any refactoring it's best to take baby steps. Move one function only, run it and make sure it works, move another, run it, etc. That way when something does blow up (and it always does) you won't be stuck digging through 500 lines of code that used to work trying to find the one thing that broke.